# Facebook SDK on iOS Graph How to return video list

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I have a graph request like:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                          initWithGraphPath:@"/me/albums"
                                          parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, picture, count"}
                                          HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
            [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error) {
```

with these permissions:

```
self.but_FacebookConnect.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_photos", @"user_videos"];
```

All my albums are there except for videos.

If I do a request on Facebook Graph API tool with /me/videos it also gives me a empty data[].
I tried with another account that has lots of videos... and this request /{user-id}/videos returned just one video.

Does anyone know if I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

the endpoint to receive the video list was /me/videos/uploaded